# Secure jsonp ajax calls

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jsonp

I have developed Restful Web-Service which returns jsonp objects. I am using this Web-Service in simple HTML page using Ajax calls. Means at client side there is only HTML page which access this Web-Service. No server used at client side. My just running this page browser. Problem is anyone can access this Web-Service I have implemented. I want to make it secure by some kind of authentication. I have read solution to send token along with request but at client side I don't have any server or anything, its just a simple HTML page. Please help me with some solution to secure Web-Service.

JavaScipt function to call webseive:

```
function calculatePremium(investmentAmount,month, premium)
{
var url = "http://192.1.200.107:8080/webresources/avestWebService/getPremium";
var payLoadData = {
    amount: $("#"+investmentAmount).val(),
    period: $("#"+month).val()
};

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    cache:false,             
    crossDomain:true,
    data: payLoadData,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function (data,textStatus,jqXHR) {
        $("#"+premium).val(data.premium);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown) {
        alert('Error occured');
    }
})
};
```

Answer (score 0):

With ajax request you can send authentication headers

```
beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + "username:password");
},
```

or insert authentication data with:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    username: "user",
    password: "password",
    ....
}
```

but you have to handle authentication by yourself in your web-service.
Or you could add with the var payLoadData some custom authentication data which you check with your web-service.

You should also consider to make the connection under https if you don't want other people to intercept your authentication packets

Comment: BUt the problem is username and password will be visible to client as it is hard coded with JavaScript. So anyone can access the web-service. I want proper authentication of this.

Comment: so you want the client to send auth data withouth allowing the client to find them?

Comment: I'm not completely shure about what you need.... You want to give a web page to a client and this page can access your web-service. Then you allow him to access your web-service, withouth allowing him to give the access to someone else? 
In that case maybe you can allow connections only from him ip address, but he must have a static one